# innerHTML codes not working if program requires time to run?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a Python program that takes roughly around 5 to 6 seconds to run before generating output. This output is to be 'feed' into an HTML page. A javascript is written to facilitate this series of action:
1. Get today's date
2. Feed today's date into python, which will access a Googlesheet database and return an output which will be passed back to the Javascript
3. Javascript places this output into the page via the `document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML` method.

My HTML page is not reflecting the change and shows default HTML text. I have decided to leave out my Python-code because I know the python program works the way it's intended to be. But I'll be happy to supplement it if needed. Hopefully, someone could help me out please:

test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Timetrack</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="writeToFrontend()"> 
        <div id="clockingMode">Loading...</div>
    <script src="../attendance_mod.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

function getCurrentDate() {
    // These are just some codes to get today's date
    var tmonth=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

    var d=new Date();
    var nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getFullYear();
    if(ndate<=9) ndate="0"+ndate;
    var todayDate = ndate+"-"+tmonth[nmonth]+"-"+nyear;

    console.log('Today\'s Date is: '+todayDate);
    return todayDate;
}

function activatePython() {
    // Today's date is fed into Python program to generate an output message, output message intended to go into HTML
    let options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonPath: 'env/bin/python',
        pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
        scriptPath: '', // this is just the directory to the script path, do not include name of script.
        args: [getCurrentDate()]
      };

      PythonShell.run('clocking_mode.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
        console.log('results: %j', results);
        console.log(results[(results.length-1)]);
        return results[(results.length-1)];
      });
}

async function writeToFrontend() {
  var clockingMode = await activatePython()
    .then(() => document.getElementById('clockingMode').innerHTML='<p>'+clockingMode+'</p>')
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

These are the error message I got when I run inspect:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: writeToFrontend is not defined
    at onload (test.html:8)
onload @ test.html:8

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: when do call `writeToFrontend()` ?

Comment: provide the complete scenario, your codes doesn't make sense;

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A writeToFrontend() is called at test.html body onload.
This is my full code less python. Do you also need my python codes?